# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException When I try to add a variable to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I'm trying to save numbers to an array through Scanner Input but
  "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" keeps popping up.

Here is my code:

```
for (int counter = 1;1==1;counter++) {
            int bucky[] = new int[counter];
            int scan = oof.nextInt();
            bucky[counter] = scan;
            if (counter == 5) {
                System.out.println(bucky);
            }
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong or where I'm going wrong in my thought process?

Comment: What is the first index of an array? Assuming its length is 1, what is its last index? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: in additiion to previous comment: 1) move array creation out of the for-loop. 2) Why not use `ArrayList` instead of array?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (int counter = 1;1==1;counter++) {
            int bucky[] = new int[counter];
            int scan = oof.nextInt();
            bucky[counter-1] = scan;
            if (counter == 5) {
                System.out.println(bucky);
            }
```

> One array of 5 positions {0,1,2,3,4}
>
> Your Array have 1 position {0}
>
> bucky[counter-1] = scan;

Comment: im getting werid outputs like [I@16d3586

Comment: is this a glitch in the compiler or something

Comment: @DudeManGuy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: @DudeManGuy handy rule of thumb: it's **never** a glitch the compiler (;->)